# Make the middle section of the page resize to the rest of the space that's left by the bottom section?

Tags: css, flexbox

So I have a header (that's absolute and over the google map)

Then the screen space should be splitted between the middle section, the breadcrumbs and footer (which stick to the bottom).

I'm supporting IE>10 so i'm using flexbox.

The header, footer and breadcrumbs should  be visible all the time, the middle section should be resized to what's left of the space, and the  contents (without the titles) of the left and right widgets of the middle section should have scrollbars if they exceed the size of the parent (the middle section, it's colored by a teal border).

I don't want the parent section to be scrollable, I want the widget contents (`.widget__content`) to be scrollable.

Here's the html structure

```
 <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='header'>
        <div class="header__txt">
            header text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='map-and-overlay'>
        <div class='map'></div>
        <div class='map-overlay'>
            <div class='widget widget-left'>
                <div class="widget__title">
                  Widget Title
                </div>
                <div class="widget__content">
                    <ul>
                        <li>item here</li>
                        <li>item here</li>
                        <li>item here</li>
                        <li>item here</li>
                        <li>item here</li>
                        <li>item here</li>
                        <li>item here</li>
                        <li>item here</li>
                        <li>item here</li>
                        <li>item here</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='widget widget-right'>
                <div class="widget__title">
                  Widget Title
                </div>
                <img src="http://unsplash.it/500/300" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='breadcrumbs'>breadcrumbs</div>
    <div class='footer'>footer</div>
 </div>
```

I made a codepen of it, if someone could help me solve this with flexbox it would be great.

Thanks!
**[MYPEN](http://codepen.io/kitze/pen/EreIs/?editors=110)**

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, I have made a few changes. If I have gone wrong anywhere or misunderstood ill change answer.

Basically you want to split the 2 boxes in the content to use the whole box and shrink when the page is being shrunk for this you will need to add a width to both boxes and use percentage to do it.

```
.widget-left{
background-color:green;
border:2px solid black;
margin-bottom:30px;
display:flex;
min-width:150px;
width: 50%;
}

.widget-right{
background-color:orange;
border:2px solid black;
margin-left:15px;
width: 50%;
}
```

*(You could also add a height and set that to a percentage if you wanted to)*

Then you want them to be able to scroll the content when it exceeds the box space, you just need to change one line.

```
   overflow-y:scroll;
```

**Change to**

```
   overflow-y:auto;
```

This will only show a scroll when the content exceeds and it wont always be visible.